# PhpStorm input dialog color

Tags: phpstorm, application-settings

Some dialog windows of PhpStorm are using a black color to text and over a black background sometimes is hard to read.

Can I change the color of these inputs using some settings?

[image: current style of dialog system]

**EDIT**: The behaviour can be simulated selecting the theme `Darcula` and the scheme `Default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "EDIT: The behaviour can be simulated selecting the theme Darcula and the scheme Default"

It is expected behavior in your case -- you are trying to use **dark** GUI Theme (Darcula) with **light** Color Schema (Editor area colors) which meant to work with **light** GUI Themes.

---

But yes -- such color is possible to change.

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`
3. `Text | Default Text`
4. Change/Assign desired color to `Foreground` styling option

Changing colors:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

**P.S.**
I've used Darcula GUI Theme + Default Color Schema.

It's possible that you may need to restart IDE for other combinations.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the problem related to that combination and what the foreground used to default text would be used in dialog search (and others dialogs) ; )

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the settings maybe possibly fix the problem

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/project-and-ide-settings.html

Comment: Thanks, goot to know ; )